# Having an ORDERBY link to sort results using AJAX jQuery from database

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I have a pagination system to go through a large set of database query results. This uses jQuery AJAX to communicate with a page which loads all of the data by queries etc.. then returns the results to the page.

```
if($pageType == 'prizeHome'){

        $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=prizes&showposts='.$per_page.'&meta_key=pointsvalue&orderby=meta_value_num&order=asc&paged='.$page);
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);
```

This is a snippet of my code. It uses wordpress query to pull in the data and also order by a meta value. My question is, if I have another parameter selected by the user saying "sort the results by points, or alphabetically", how does this stay true when the user clicks to go to the next page?

I may be a little confused as to how to even go about doing this, maybe I need to use some sort of jQuery cookie so the site remembers what order the user has selected?

I'ld appreciate any input, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a query parameter to hold the chosen sort field (to allow for bookmarks, back/forward etc). E.g. `www.site.com/page?sortBy=name`

To remember the setting, the link to the next page should contain the query parameter as well.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but would this be done using javascript? Like an onclick event when the user clicks "orderby: points" for example?

Comment: Well, you could fairly easily use jQuery to modify URLs on the current page so if that is your preference, yes. The other option if you use classic server pages is to handcraft the URLs on the server side before serving the page to the browser.